# How to fetch API into VUEX

Tags: api, vue.js, vuex

I use VUEX that store some id, and use that id into function, here's my code:

vuex/**getDocumentId.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

const module = {
    namespace: true,
    state: () => ({
            id: ''
    }),
    mutations: {
        getDocumentId(state, repoId) {
            state.id = repoId
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async fetchDocumentRepoId({ commit }) {
            const response = await axios.get('api/json')
            console.log(response.data)
            commit('getDocumentId', response.data)
        }
    }
}

export default module;
```

I use separate file to declare in store/index

store/index

```
import getDocumentId from "@/store/documentService/getDocumentId";
Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      getDocumentId
    }
})
```

the api looks like this

```
26kdjgg564khdhzg: {
  id: '26kdjgg564khdhzg',
  idName: 'Intern'
  ...
}
```

and I wanna access the id in another js file like this

```
() {
...
const url = this.$store.state.getDocumentId.id
return `${url}`
...
}
```

The Vuex Debug look like this

```
id: object 
  26kdjgg564khdhzg: object
    id: '26kdjgg564khdhzg',
    idName: 'Intern'
  ...
}
```

how can I access the `key: 26kdjgg564khdhzg` or `id: '26kdjgg564khdhzg'` ?

Comment: given the one example object you posted, the inner object can be extracted after fetching like `Object.values(response.data)[0]`

Comment: where should I put that? My async fetchDocumentId commit?

Comment: If there's nothing else you need from the original object you can extract the data immediately from `response.data` so as soon as you have `response` you can do it then